# Print contents of a mysql table in txt format

Tags: php, html, mysql, implementation

I am working on a web application (php, javascript, html) that holds a large amount os user information. It is designed for temporary jobs.

The thing is, I have three tables (mysql) with information about the users. One for the address and other things, other for driver license, certificates, ..., and the last one for user experience.

What I want to do, is have a "print" button that generates a txt file with all that data in one file. The thing is that I alredy have an idea of how to do it.

1) retrieve all the information for the tables in a join with username.
2) I already had the function to "resource_to_array" for building an array with all the data
3) I could just go for each column of the array and saving the information that I want

But what I am asking is for experience doing something like this. This is the first time for me, and I want it to make it good and scalable for the future.

How will be a good way to do implement it? also, how could I create a plain text with all that information? (this part is in where I have more doubts about)

I know that maybe is a weird question..but I do not want code, I just want a vision for the implementation. Also, is there is a library os something similar that do what I want to do

Thank you very much.

Comment: `<?php echo 'this is plain text'; ?>`. html is text. PHP code is text. if you want "plain" text, then don't output any html tags.

Comment: http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2004/09/21/10-minutes-to-printer-friendly-page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make a link that will generate text file.

```
<a href="print.php">Print</a>
```

Now, in `print.php` you have to put your logic.

1. Execute the join Query for fetching the data.
2. Fetch `"array"` for building an array with all the data.
3. Get the element from the array that you want to save in `text` file.
4. Now logic is here, Use `file handling` for creating the text file with save data.

**Logic is here(print.php) :**

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("host-name","username","password","database-name");

$query = "....";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
   $data = $rs['column-name']; // data you want to save in text file

$f = fopen("save.txt", 'a');
     fwrite($f, $data);
     fclose($f);

}

   $filename = "save-data.txt"; // name of the file you want to download on clicking the link 
    $file = "save-data.txt";
    $type = filetype($file);
    // Send file headers
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
    header('Expires: 0');
    // Send the file contents.
    set_time_limit(0); 
    readfile($file);

?>
```

Sidenote: The `a` switch appends to file. If you do not wish to keep adding to it, use the `w` switch:

```
$f = fopen("save.txt", 'w');
```

I hope it will help you.